# Mark radio as checked when the user click in line<tr> of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table where all line have a input(type:radio) as an rowid.
In this way, I want mark the input as checked when the user click at line from the respective radio and so on in all lines.

Comment: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/e4ayc7vz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('tr').on('click' ,function(){
   $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked':true);
});
```

When you click any TR find the radio's inside it and check them manually

Comment: Works guy. Thank you! But I changed: .prop('checked':true') by .prop('checked',true)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#rowId').on('click', function() {
  $('#radioIdForRow').prop('checked', true);
}.bind(this));
```

This is the same as @joyBlanks's answer, but gives you the flexibility to have the radio button not be within the DOM tree of the row.

Comment: Doesn't this have the issue of using an ID as a selector based on context, or worse yet, using the same ID in multiple places?

Comment: @Orpheus I use two different IDs in my example to show that he should have two IDs. Good call on the `this`. I added a bind to keep it as the parent.

Comment: @psylogic that's correct. Again, this is meant to be a solution where the radio button node is not a sibling or child of the row node, something that is required of joyBlanks answer.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case.
But thanks anyway for your help.